# DataContract IsReference only working one way?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, serialization

I have a base class from which all my model classes inherit - Entity.  Entity is decorated with

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

That worked with going from client to server (a save operation).  But I'm now getting the same error I was before I added IsReference when going from server to client (a get operation).  Any ideas?

Edit:

The error is:

> There was an error while trying to
>   serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:GetResult. The
>   InnerException message was 'Object
>   graph for type
>   'Current.Entities.LazyList`1[[Current.Entities.SubPart,
>   Current.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles
>   and cannot be serialized if reference
>   tracking is disabled.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Edit:

Shoot, I answered this but have since deleted it. I thought I fixed it due to something else I did in the project. I was wrong, this is still causing me an issue. I have a little bit more information - the server-to-client error only happens if an entity in the object graph contains a non-empty LazyList of children. If the list is empty then there's no problem.

Comment: I never found this fix to this and had to implement a work-around by doing my own serialization with JSON.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.preserveobjectreferences.aspx flag should fix this. (The flag also exists on DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior -- in config, via the DataContract attribute, and via any custom behaviors you inherit)